# How can I reduce an operation with a subscript?

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

```
expenses = [
    ('Dinner', 80),
    ('Car repair', 120),
    ('csgo skins', 200)
]

# Version with for-loop
sum = 0
for expense in expenses:
    sum += expense[1]
print(sum)

# Version using lambda+reduce
sum2 = reduce((lambda a, b: a[1] + b[1]), expenses)
print(sum2)
```

I'm trying to obtain, with `lambda` and `reduce`, the same result that I had with the for-loop version.

If the `expenses` list contains only 2 items, everything works fine, but if I add more I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r:\Developing\_Python\lambda_map_filter_reduce.py", line 44, in <module>
    sum2 = reduce((lambda a, b: a[1] + b[1]), expenses)
  File "r:\Developing\_Python\lambda_map_filter_reduce.py", line 44, in <lambda>
    sum2 = reduce((lambda a, b: a[1] + b[1]), expenses)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `total = sum(expense[1] for expense in expenses)`

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know you could do it also in this way. But i would like to use lambda in the process. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're returning an `int` from your lambda, which will become `a` in the next iteration. `a[1]` obviously makes no sense then…

Comment: @Ceccoclat Why do you want to use a lambda?

Comment: @Tom McLean This is the exact copy pasta of the code of a video lesson, but i couldnt extend it to more than 2 items per list, so here i am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that `reduce` calls itself with the result from the previous `reduce` operation as its first argument. So `a[1]` no longer makes sense because on the second and subsequent iterations, `a` is the sum returned from the previous iteration.

You can painfully get around this with an explicit special case, of course; or, you can pass in a sequence which removes this obstacle:

```
from operator import itemgetter
...
sum2 = reduce(
   lambda a, b: a + b,
   map(itemgetter(1), expenses))
print(sum2)
```

`itemgetter` is a convenience function for fetching an item at a particular subscript. So, we are basically passing `x[1] for x in expenses` to `reduce` instead of the original list.

Chaining transformations like this is one of the cornerstones of functional programming. The paradigm gently nudges you to rethink your problem into simple operations which fit together elegantly.

Demo: https://ideone.com/KnqksZ

As pointed out by @deceze, you could further prettify this;

```
from operator import add, itemgetter
...
sum2 = reduce(add, map(itemgetter(1), expenses))
print(sum2)
```

In still other words, the `map` part of `map+reduce` should produce a transformation of the input which is suitable for `reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your reduce + lambda version so that now it is using accumulator as well provided at start, will work for any number of tuples in the list

```
from functools import reduce

expenses = [
    ('Dinner', 80),
    ('Car repair', 120),
    ('csgo skins', 200)
]

# Version with for-loop
sum = 0
for expense in expenses:
    sum += expense[1]
print(sum)

# Version using lambda+reduce
sum2 = reduce(lambda accumulator, expense: accumulator + expense[1], expenses, 0)
print(sum2)
```

> 400 400

Comment: Perhaps spell out that specifying an _initializer_ allows you to uniformly receive the "previous" result in the first argument to the `lambda`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Comment: Yes you selected the right combination of words to explain :D